# Guzzle HTTP - Skip if Exception Present or Page Not Found

Tags: php, html, laravel, dom, guzzle

I am trying to create a try/catch loop that I am using for downloading HTML from another website:

```
foreach($intldes as $id) {
    $html = HtmlDomParser::file_get_html('https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraftDisplay.do?id='.$id); 
    foreach($html->find('#rightcontent') as $id);
    foreach($html->find('.urone p') as $element);
    foreach($html->find('.urtwo') as $launchdata); 
}
```

If the data exists, it results in the following HTML:

```html
<p><strong>NSSDCA/COSPAR ID:</strong> 2009-038F</p>
<p>ANDE 2, the Atmospheric Neutral Density Experiment 2, is a pair of microsatellites (Castor and Pollux) launched from Cape Canaveral on STS 127 on 15 July 2009 at 22:03 UT and deployed from the payload bay of the shuttle on 30 July 2009 at 17:22 UT.</p>
<p><strong>Launch Date:</strong> 2009-07-15<br/><strong>Launch Vehicle:</strong> Shuttle<br/><strong>Launch Site:</strong> Cape Canaveral, United States<br/></p>
```

If the data does not exist, I get a `Undefined variable: element` error, which means that the DOM Parser could not find the HTML that I want to display.

So I need a something that skips the webpages that do not have the required HTML or a variable of NULL returned.

Basically, if the HTML I want or the variable `$element` does not exist, I want Guzzle to skip that webpage and not load it.

**EDIT:**

My full function:

```
    public function tester() {
    $intldes = DB::table('examples')->pluck('id');
    foreach ($intldes as $query) {
        $html = HtmlDomParser::file_get_html('https://example.com?id='.$query); 
        $elements = $html->find('.urone p', 0);
    if (is_array($elements)) {
        foreach($html->find('#rightcontent') as $rawid);
        foreach($html->find('.urone p') as $rawdescription);
        foreach($html->find('.urtwo') as $launchdata); 

        //-- Data Parser --//
        //Intldes
        $intldesgetter = strip_tags($rawid->first_child()->next_sibling()->next_sibling()); //Get Element and Remove Tags
        $intldesformat = substr($intldesgetter, ($pos = strpos($intldesgetter, ':')) !== false ? $pos + 3 : 0); //Remove Title
        $dbintldes = ltrim($intldesformat); //Remove Blank-space

        //Description
        $description = strip_tags($rawdescription);
        $dbdescription = ltrim($description);

        //Launch Data
        $launchdate = $launchdata->first_child()->next_sibling()->next_sibling()->next_sibling();
        $explode = explode("<br/>", $launchdate);
        $newArray = array_map(function($v){
            return trim(strip_tags($v));
        }, $explode);
        $dblaunchdate = substr($newArray[0], ($pos = strpos($newArray[0], ':')) !== false ? $pos + 3 : 0);
        $dblaunchvehicle = substr($newArray[1], ($pos = strpos($newArray[1], ':')) !== false ? $pos + 3 : 0);
        $dblaunchsite = substr($newArray[2], ($pos = strpos($newArray[2], ':')) !== false ? $pos + 3 : 0);

        //Data Saver
        DB::table('descriptions')->insert(
            ['intldes' => $dbintldes, 'description' => strip_tags($dbdescription), 'launch_date' => $dblaunchdate, 'launch_vehicle' => $dblaunchvehicle, 'launch_site' => $dblaunchsite]
        );
        echo "Success"; 
        } else {
            echo "$query does not exist";
            continue;
        };
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting error here in your code:

```
foreach($html->find('.urone p') as $element);
```

From my experience, I would recommend to you that you should check for the availability of the **HTML tag** first before iterating in the **foreach** loop.

You can use either `is_object()` or `is_array()` to get work around your problem. When you search for a single element, an object is returned. When you search for a set of elements, an array of objects is returned.

As you are searching for set of elements then you can use

```
$elements = $html->find('.urone p');
if (is_array($elements)) {
    //continue
}
```

Comment: Just tried that. It works if the `$elements` does exist, but it results in an `Undefined variable` error when it does not exist.

Comment: You can try `$element = $html->find('.urone p', 0)` and then check if `$element` is null or not

Comment: Nope still did not work - I am thinking that I am doing something wrong. Just to give you some background on the problem I am having: I pull a column from my database. I then create a URL `foreach` with the data from the column - so the URL is /1, /2, /3, etc (anything that is in my column I pulled). What we are currently trying to do is to skip if the URL for example, /6 does not exist. We doing this using the HTML `if` statement that you provided in your question.

Comment: I have given you my whole function - maybe you can see what is wrong with it? Thanks!

Comment: You can create your URL dynamically, that is not the problem. It is clearly mentioned here http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm that `$ret = $html->find('a', 0);` will throw null if not found